# how could i optimize a view in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i am trying to improve the physical design of my database for optimizing the performance of some processes but i don´t know how could improve this view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CP_aragna AS (
SELECT nick, 100*sum(nuls)/count('c') pct_aragna 
  FROM (SELECT nick,club,title,director,
               NVL2(msg_date,0,1) nuls 
           FROM (SELECT member nick, club, title, director 
                    FROM proposals) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN comments 
                USING(nick,club,title,director) 
       )
   GROUP BY nick
   HAVING sum(nuls)>0
) order by pct_aragna desc WITH READ ONLY;
```

I thought about creating a materialized view or indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the query:

```
SELECT p.nick,
       AVG(CASE WHEN c.msg_date IS NOT NULL THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as pct_aragno
FROM proposals p LEFT JOIN
     comments c
     USING (nick, club, title, director) 
GROUP BY p.nick
HAVING COUNT(c.msg_date) > 0 
ORDER BY pct_aragna DESC;
```

Oracle has a good optimizer, so this probably will not affect performance.

This suggests that you have a four-part foreign key relationship.  For this version, be sure that you have an index on `comments(nick, club, title, director, msg_date)`.  Oracle can probably take advantage of an index on `proposals(nick)` for the `group by` as well.

However, such complex foreign key relationships are prone to error.  I would suggest that you use an auto-generated integer primary key to connect the tables.  That would have some impact on performance, because those four columns would not be needed in `comments` -- saving most of the space that those four columns need.